# php sql check inactive users

Tags: php, sql

I would like to list members which have not logged in within 90 days. In mysql I have a
last_access column which updates every time a user logs in. So i think the check can be performed on this column. The columns format is: `date("Y/m/d : H:i:s", time())`   (2011/05/10 : 21:42:33)

What would be an appropriate SQL query to use?

Comment: Why are you using a nonstandard date format? You should really use a UNIX timestamp in an INT column or a DATETIME column.

Comment: What type of field is this value stored in?

Comment: Don't tell us you're storing the date in a varchar column for *readability*.

Comment: OK, I think I can tweak my query to work with VARCHAR but still, any plan about converting the field and data to a DATETIME type?

Comment: Yeah, i converted it to datetime (  `last_access` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',) and date now storing  with NOW()  (insert into members (user, pass, last_access) VALUES ($username, $pass, NOW())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username
FROM users
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),last_access)>90
```

Comment: This assumes that `last_access` is a column with a proper date/time type. If that's not the case, if @Zero is actually using a string as he suggests, it's advisable to fix the column type rather than implementing a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT columns
FROM table
WHERE last_access < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 90 DAY
```